# Need to cross reference two lists of Vendor Names/Numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare, ms-office, excel-2013

I have two lists of vendor names/numbers in four total columns.  I've attached a picture of sample data

[image: Example Data]..

What I need to do is if a vendor name in column D is in column B, I need to pull both vendor numbers so that I can compare the two and create a cross reference list.

So, in my examples, I need to pull A2/B2 to compare with C3/D3.

How can I do this?

Comment: see [vlookup or match/index](http://mrexcel.com/articles/excel-vlookup-index-match.php)

Comment: I've got to dig up one of my older [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) responses so I can close these off as duplicates.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I get that those functions may help, but do not know how to utilize them.  I tried VLOOKUP but the columns do not match up, the same vendor names could be anywhere and that was giving me trouble

Comment: But There is another part @Jeeped, the OP wants a list of matching names to which he then can use a lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the list of matches, use this Array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$5,$B$2:$B$5),ROW($1:$4)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Being an Array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

I put it in F2 and Copied down.

Then referencing that column I used the following two formulas:

```
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,B:B,0)),"")
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F2,D:D,0)),"")
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

For large amounts of data forget the first formula and use the Existing column D as the reference for the two latter formulas:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D2,B:B,0)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D2,D:D,0)),"")
```

[image]

Then Sort descending by column E:

[image]

Comment: Just waiting for the OP to say that his/her 30K rows are taking too long to calculate.

Comment: @Jeeped just because it would do 2^30000 calculations is no reason to complain. :) yeah that would take a second or two.

Comment: Ha, yep, that's pretty much where I'm at.  Want to check on my formula.. what parts do I change to make it work for 30,000+ rows? Here's what I currently have:

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(D:D,B:B),ROW($1:$50000)),ROW(30159:30159))),"")

Comment: @DominicG. this is not what you want to do if you have that many rows, the calculation time would be too large.

Comment: I don't care if it will take 5-10 mins or something.  Do i have another option?

Comment: @DominicG. you are talking about 30159*2^30159 calculation it would take quite a while.  See Edit.  If you really want to go the other way, you would change all the `5`s to 30159 and the 4 to 30158. `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$30159,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$30159,$B$2:$B$30159),ROW($1:$30158)),ROW(1:1))),"")`.  Avoid full column references in Array formulas.  You can try both ways and see which you like better.

Comment: So one column only has 470 items.  the other one has 30,000.  currently this is my formula:

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$469,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$30158,$B$1:$B$469),ROW($1:$30158)),ROW(1:1))),"")

Comment: @DominicG. does it work? Are you entering it in as an Array by hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter?  Do you only have one cell chosen when doing this?  I need more info if it is not working.

Comment: The Ctrl+Shift+Enter is not working for me, its all blank i do not get results.  I am typing the formula in F1 and getting nothing

Comment: Select F1.  Do you see`{}` around the formula?  If not then you are not entering it in correctly.  But I just realized the row count has to match the number of rows in Column B so: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$469,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$30158,$B$1:$B$469),ROW($1:$469)),ROW(1:1))),"") `

Comment: I fixed it by removing the dollar sign before 1

Comment: @DominicG. No don't do that, I just tested this `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$469,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$30158,$B$1:$B$469),ROW($1:$‌​469)),ROW(1:1))),"")` and it works. It takes a while to calculate about a minute or two but it works. If you remove the $ in front of the 1 it will change as you drag the formula down.

Comment: So i think it worked correctly, but those latter two formulas aren't working now.. just getting blanks

Comment: @DominicG. So in G1 you have `=IF(F1<>"",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F1,B:B,0)),"")` and in H1 `=IF(F2<>"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F2,D:D,0)),"")`? These are non array formulas and get entered normally.

Comment: the first one worked, the second one is returning the same as first

Comment: @DominicG. are you sure that they are different in the two columns?  this finds the first value that is the same name and returns the column to the left value.  Double check that they are not the same in the two columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner looks like things are working well.  Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it.